# how to delete a sub element in mongoose, undefined does not work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
    job.vote.census = undefined;
```

This does not work.

vote is an object that has a few keys, which are arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"? Show your schema and a sample document to explain what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bypassing mongoose completely and just running the migration on mongo directly (using robomongo for mac):

Test with one first:

```
db.jobs.update({ _id: ObjectId("xxx") }, { $unset: { "vote.census": "" }})
```

Backup db first, this will apply to all jobs:

```
db.jobs.update({}, { $unset: { "vote.census": "" }}, { multi: true })
```

You can backup your mongo db with:

```
mongodump --db $db --host $host -u $user --password $pass
tar czf ./$file ./dump
```